# Prove $ L^2[0,1] \subseteq L^1[0,1]$ has no interior points

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I am trying to understand the following problem done by my professor:

**Prove explicitly that $L^2[0, 1]$ as vector subspace of $L^1[0, 1]$ has no interior points**

**Suggestion:** It is enough to show that for each element of $L^2[0, 1]$ it is possible to construct a sequence of elements belonging to $L^1[0; 1] \setminus L^2[0, 1]$ which converges in $L^1[0, 1] $ to that element

Solution:
Let $f \in L^2[0,1] \subseteq L^1[0,1]$. Let's consider $\varepsilon\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let's define
$$ g_n(x)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x^{1-\varepsilon}} &, 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{n} \\0 & \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1  
 \end{cases} $$
and $$f_n=f+g_n ...(\alpha)$$

We observe that
$$ \text{Since }\;\;\;1-\varepsilon \in [1/2,1] \;\;\;|| g_n ||_1 = \int_0^1 |g_n(x)|dx = \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{1}{x^{1-\varepsilon}}= \frac{1}{\varepsilon n^{\varepsilon}} $$
$$\text{Since  }\;\;\;2-2\varepsilon \in [1,2] \;\;\; || g_n ||_2 = \int_0^1 |g_n(x)|^2dx = \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{1}{x^{2-2\varepsilon}}= +\infty $$
Then $g_n \in L^1[0; 1] \setminus L^2[0, 1] $

So $f_n \in L^1[0; 1] \setminus L^2[0, 1] ...(\beta)$

and besides
$$ ||f-f_n||_1 =||g_n||_1 \to 0 \text{ when } n \to + \infty \iff f_n \to f \text{ in } L^1[0,1] ...(\gamma)$$

I understand we found $g_n\in L^1[0; 1] \setminus L^2[0, 1]$. **But I don't understand the role of $f_n$ here, why are they introducing it for at $(\alpha)$, how are they concluding $f_n \in L^1[0; 1] \setminus L^2[0, 1] $at   $(\beta)$ and what are doing at $(\gamma)$?**
Can someone shed some some light?

Comment: I would rather suggest showing that the only open sub-vectorspace of a normed space / TVS is the original space itself (if a sub-space has interior points it must be open, since every point is interior by translation). Then showing that your inclusion is strict by finding a function in $L^1$ that is not in $L^2$.

Comment: thanks, this proof was done by my professor and I am trying to make sense of it.

Comment: @ s.harp what do you mean with " interior by translation", the only definition of interior point I know is that there exist an open ball centered in the point and contained in the set

Comment: If $U$ is a neighbourhood of $p$ contained entirely in the vector space then for $x$ in the space $(x-p)+U$ is also contained entirely in the vector space and is an open neighbourhood of $x$, ie if you translate the neighbourhood it remains a neighbourhood.